# HttpErrorInterceptor not redirecting in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, angular-http-interceptors

I'm trying to make a global error interceptor so that on each and every error it would redirect to main page with `error=true` query parameter. Somehow it catches the error, logs it but doesn't redirect. What am I doing wrong?

HttpErrorInterceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request)
      .pipe(
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          let errorMsg = '';
          if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
            errorMsg = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
          } else {
            errorMsg = `Error Code: ${error.status},  Message: ${error.message}`;
          }
          const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
          this.router.navigate(['main'], {queryParams: {error: true, sesskey: urlParams.get('sesskey')}});
          console.log(errorMsg);
          return throwError(errorMsg);
        })
      )
  }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: HttpErrorInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is working, how did you test it

for me it works like this

```
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
    const url = 'Fake url';
    return this.http.get(url).subscribe();
  }
}
```